# How to dynamically create n arrays?

Tags: javascript

I have this object:

```
public obj: any = { row1: [], row2: [], total: [], sumTotal: 0, count: 0 };
```

How can i create n empty arrays ?

Im trying something like this but its not working:

```
if (this.i === 0) { this.obj.row['_' + this.row] = new Array(); }
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Here you expect to create 3 arrays?

Comment: You probably want an array of arrays then. And you can use a loop to fill your array of arrays.

Comment: i expect to create n arrays...depend how many time i will be 0 .

Comment: i want to create new empty arrays with new name

Comment: on which base you decided the number of arrays?

Comment: if (this.i === 0) its index of arary and it will be n time with value 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `if (this.i === 0) { this.obj.row['_' + this.row] = new Array(); }`

You have to create the `row` property a little different. The way you typed it would try to access `this.obj.row`, in other words the `row` property of the `obj` property of `this`. And on that object, you would try to access the property `'_' + this.row`.

Below you find the correct solution. Just include the word `row` and omit the underscore:

```js
if (this.i === 0) { this.obj['row' + this.row] = new Array(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create object like this

```
let length = 15;// Whatever you want
for(let i=0;i<length;i++){
  if(this.obj['row'+i] === undefined){
    this.obj['row'+i] = [];
  }
}
```